# Java ENUM with logical OR selection

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I would like to implement a method that returns one or a list of allowed Action defined as enum.

For example my method should be like this:

```
public enum getAllowedActions() {
  return // (( 'something like' Actions.ACTION1 & Actions.ACTION2 ));
}
```

and then read the results in another position like:

```
if (getAllowedActions() == Actions.ACTION1) {
  // do something...
}
```

with:

```
public class enum {
  ACTION1, ACTION2;
}
```

Thanks.
Stefano.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you're just lookng for [`EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html):

```
public EnumSet<Action> getAllowedActions() {
    return EnumSet.of(Action.ACTION1, Action.ACTION2);
}

...
if (getAllowedAction().contains(Action.ACTION1)) {
    ...
}
```